# How can I get javascript 'add to cart' function to work when shopping cart is in separate html page? Unsure how to apply local storage to my code

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, checkout, shopping-cart

(New to JavaScript)

With the help of a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeFzkC2awTM) I created a custom shopping cart for my website.

When the items added to the cart are on the same page as the cart/checkout, they are tallied up in the checkout total successfully.
However, I want the cart to be on a separate HTML page to the items, so that when the user is finished adding items to the cart they may navigate there to see their total and complete checkout.

But when I put the items on a separate HTML page and add them to the cart, the cart no longer updates. I figure the problem is because I have not specified any storage, so when I navigate to the cart the page is refreshed and the stored variables are lost (?)

I'm not sure how to implement local storage with the code I have created.

Any help much appreciated!

HTML Code for items page:

```
      <div class="ticket-name">EARLY BIRD</div>
         <div class="ticket-details">
            <span class="ticket-price">€20.99</span>
            <button class="btn ticket-button" type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
         </div>
      </div>
```

HTML Code for shopping cart page:

```
                        <div class="cart-row">
                            <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                            <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                            <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
                        </div>

                        <!-- HTML5 div tag for the items in the cart -->
                        <!-- This div will be populated with HTML using JavaScript -->
                        <div class="cart-items">

                        </div>

                        <!-- HTML5 div tag for the total for items in the cart -->
                        <div class="cart-total">
                            <strong class="cart-total-title">Total</strong>
                            <span class="cart-total-price">€0</span>
                        </div>

                        <!-- HTML5 button to purchase items -->
                        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">

                            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="weblectricvirtualfestival@gmail.com">
                            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
                            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Festival Tickets">
                            <input id="paypal-price" type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">
                            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
                            <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
                            <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
                            <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
                            <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"
                                name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                            <img alt="" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">

                        </form>

                    </div>
```

JS code for shopping cart:

```
    if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
        } else {
            ready()
        }

        function ready() {

            var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
            for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
                var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
                button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
            }

            var quantityInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')
            for (var i = 0; i < quantityInputs.length; i++) {
                var input = quantityInputs[i]
                input.addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
            }

            var addToCartButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('ticket-button')
            for (var i = 0; i < addToCartButtons.length; i++) {
                var button = addToCartButtons[i]
                button.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked)
            }
        }

        function removeCartItem(event) {
            var buttonClicked = event.target
            buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove()
            updateCartTotal()
        }

        function quantityChanged(event) {
            var input = event.target
            if (isNaN(input.value) || input.value <= 0) {
                input.value = 1
            }
            updateCartTotal()
        }

        function addToCartClicked(event) {
            var button = event.target
            var shopItem = button.parentElement.parentElement
            var title = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('ticket-name')[0].innerText
            var price = shopItem.getElementsByClassName('ticket-price')[0].innerText
            addItemToCart(title, price)
            updateCartTotal()
        }

        function addItemToCart(title, price) {
            var cartRow = document.createElement('div')
            cartRow.classList.add('cart-row')
            var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
            var cartItemNames = cartItems.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')

            for (var i = 0; i < cartItemNames.length; i++) {
                if (cartItemNames[i].innerText == title) {
                    alert('This item is already added to the cart')
                    return
                }
            }

            var cartRowContents = `
                <div class="cart-item cart-column">
                    <span class="cart-item-title">${title}</span>
                </div>
                <span class="cart-price cart-column">${price}</span>
                <div class="cart-quantity cart-column">
                    <input class="cart-quantity-input" type="number" value="1">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">REMOVE</button>
                </div>`

            cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents
            cartItems.append(cartRow)
            cartRow.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')[0].addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
            cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0].addEventListener('change', quantityChanged)
        }

        function updateCartTotal() {
            var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
            var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
            var total = 0

            for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
                var cartRow = cartRows[i]
                var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
                var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
                var price = parseFloat(priceElement.innerText.replace('€', '')) 
                var quantity = quantityElement.value
                total = total + (price * quantity)
            }

            total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100

            document.getElementById("paypal-price").value = total;

            document.getElementsByClassName('cart-total-price')[0].innerText = '€' + total
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you having more than 1 page?

variable and array data can’t pass to other html directly by js.

1. It should be backend job.
2. You can use useContext in react if you tried to learn frontend. Single page system… just take a look.
3. Use css display:none, create fake page.

Eg: click a button, section a display none and section b display block

I think method 3 is more easy for new.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).